# React Hooks: State is resetting to empty array even if I use the spread operator, prevState, etc

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

[Simplified Code Sample right here](https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-wave-nbzuu?file=/src/InputComponent.jsx)

WORDS:
In short: My `items` state is resetting to `[]` with each NEW checkbox clicked and I dont understand why. But instead I want to use the spread operator and `useState` hooks to push an new item into the array so it's an array of objects.

Current behavior in detail: I'm creating an object and setting it in state using all (and I mean ALL) manner of React `useState` hooks like this: `setItems((prevState) => [...prevState, { [evt.target.value]: evt.target.checked }]);` As I check one item it's added and `items` becomes an array of objects (it being added over and over again is not the problem; I'll add a check for that later). BUT Here's the problem: when I click a NEW checkbox the `items` array is set back to `[]` and isnt concatenated with the prev `items`—even though I'm using `prevState`, spread operator, an arrow func as a wrapper, and all that jazz.

Desired behavior: Every time I check a checkbox, I want to update `items []` to push a new object into it, which represents all items that have ever been checked. Before you say anything about duplicating: I'll add the check to see if an item is already in the array, and just update it if so. And before I add all `items` to cart, I'll strip all objects with `checked = false` states.

Can you help me understand what react lifecycle fundamentals I'm missing here; why is this happening? And how can I fix it?

CODE:
Where this is happening:

---

Simplified version of `InputComponent`

```
const InputComponent = ({ type, itemId, handleSearchQuery, onSubmit }) => {
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

    const captureInput = (evt) => {
        if (evt.target.type === 'checkbox') {
            setItems((prevState) => [...prevState, { [evt.target.value]: evt.target.checked }]);
        }
    };

    const renderCheckbox = () => {
        return (
            <form>
                <input type={type} name={itemId} value={itemId} onChange={setItem} />
                <input name={itemId} type='submit' value='Add to Cart' />
            </form>
        );
    };

    return (
        <div className='input-bar'>
            {renderCheckbox()}
        </div>
    );
};

export default InputComponent;
```

---

Where this component is used:

```
import React from 'react';
import InputComponent from './InputComponent';
import './ResultsRenderer.css';

function ResultsRenderer({ data }) {
    const renderListings = () => {
        let listings = data ? data.Search : null;

        return listings
            ? listings.map((item) => {
                    return (
                        <div className='cart-row'>
                            <InputComponent type='checkbox' className='cart-checkbox' itemId={item.imdbID} />
                            <div key={item.imdbID} className={item.imdbID}>
                                <img src={`${item.Poster}`} alt={item.Title} />
                                <div>
                                    Title<em>{item.Title}</em>
                                </div>
                                <div>{item.Year}</div>
                                <em>{item.imdbID}</em>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    );
              })
            : null;
    };

    return <>{renderListings()}</>;
}

export default ResultsRenderer;
```

Comment: On first glance your `setItems` call seems okay other than that it shouldn't be using the event object after the event handler has returned. Please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] demonstrating the problem using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: Can you create a minimal example in codesandbox? Many of your variables are not even used, like `items`, `captureInput`, `handleSearchQuery`, `onSubmit` [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Here's your event handler without the problem of using the event object after the handler returns that I mentioned above, but I don't think that's your issue (the symptom would be different): `const captureInput = ({target: {type, value, checked}}) => { if (type === 'checkbox') { setItems((prevState) => [...prevState, { [value]: checked }]); } };`

Comment: One thing that I notice is that you're always adding to the array. What if there's already an entry for the given `value`? Wouldn't it make more sense to update it? (And if so, a `Map` rather than an array would make more sense.)

Comment: This appears to be an over-simplified/over-reduced code example as you seem to have omitted the code that calls `captureInput` to update your state in the first place, and the form is missing the `onSubmit` handler and logic to prevent a page reload. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), enough to see what the code is ***actually*** doing, steps to reproduce the issue/bug, etc...

Comment: I've added a simplified code sample. LMK if you have problems viewing it.

Comment: From what I can tell the code is doing what you coded it to do. Each input keeps the history of the checkbox toggling. If you toggle the first checkbox true, false, you'll see those state updates logged. Then toggle the second true, you'll see *that* state update logged. If you then go back and toggle the first checkbox true, you'll again see the console log, now with 3 elements in it. Are you wanting some sort of combined state of all the inputs, a single source of truth, in the parent component `ResultsRenderer`?

Comment: Did you try my solution?

Comment: if the answer was helpful try to accept the answer and give an upVote to it

Answer (score 1):

`items` state is doing its job perfectly fine, you misunderstood the situation.

you're using `items` state inside `InputComponent` and for each `listings item` there is one `InputComponent` and each one have their own `items`, I think you meant to use `items` state inside `ResultsRenderer` Component to chase all selected `items`.

here is the changes you need to do:

```
const InputComponent = ({ type, itemId, setItems }) => {
  const captureInput = (evt) => {
    if (evt.target.type === "checkbox") {
      setItems((prevState) => [
        ...prevState,
        { [evt.target.value]: evt.target.checked }
      ]);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="input-bar">
      <form>
        <input
          type={type}
          name={itemId}
          value={itemId}
          onChange={captureInput}
        />
        <input name={itemId} type="submit" value="Add to Cart" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default InputComponent;
```

```
function ResultsRenderer() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(items);
  }, [items]);

  const renderListings = () => {
    let listings = [
      { itemId: 1, title: "Hello" },
      { itemId: 2, title: "World" }
    ];

    return listings
      ? listings.map((item) => {
          return (
            <div className="cart-row">
              <InputComponent
                type="checkbox"
                className="cart-checkbox"
                itemId={item.itemId}
                setItems={setItems}
              />
              <div key={item.itemId} className={item.itemId}>
                <div>
                  Title<em>{item.Title}</em>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })
      : null;
  };

  return <>{renderListings()}</>;
}
```

and here is the working demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-cookies-t0g4e?file=/src/InputComponent.jsx

Comment: Thanks, Taghi. This works and is so simple—I just needed to move the state higher up the tree. Arrrgh trees. :) My mind was really stuck on keeping the functions of this component contained. But I couldnt see that, by doing that, my `items` object in state was different for each component. Thank you so much.

Comment: @CatPerry yes exactly, these things happens a lot, after a while, you'll use to it :)